# SharpMap UK OS data

Tags: ordnance-survey, sharpmap

I've downloaded the UK raster and the corresponding tab file from the ordnance survey website and have displayed the image using the GDARaster class. however I am now stuck as I have no idea how to use the .tab file that came with the map and how I can display points on the map using long and lat.

I can't seem to find a working example of how to do this can anyone help?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Anthony - could you add a little more information to your question? Hyperlinks to the data you mention would help.

Comment: perhaps this is close to what you are looking for. I googled "sharpmap add xy".  http://sharpmap.codeplex.com/discussions/241986

Comment: Which OS Raster dataset are you using? .tab files are native to MapInfo for georeference rasters in this case.